# How to update magento 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: magento, updates

Hiiiii guys

I have magento 1.9 but I want to update it to magento 2.0 please anyone help me how to update it? I am beginner not very good with code.

Comment: Probably fits better here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks bro. :) now go there

Answer (score 3):

You do not upgrade/update Magento 1.9.x.x to Magento 2.x

It is a **MIGRATION** process.

The database schemas are vastly different so data has to be extracted from one database and inserted into the appropriate tables/columns in the new version where it still has meaning, or discarded as no longer relevant to the way Magento 2.x works.

[Magento CE Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce)

The directory tree and function of Magento 2.x is vastly different. Modules, themes and utilities will have to be rewritten to work with it. You will have to see if your 3rd party module developers are even going to bother releasing 2.x versions and whether the released versions will function closely to what you expect currently on 1.9.x.x

[Magento Migration Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html)